# Orion Admin mashup NGSI Subscription browser widget not working properly

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to develop a Orion admin mashup on fiware lab (noida) node for my local Orion instance.I have download a Orion admin mashup from this link: [https://store.lab.fiware.org/#/offering/540] and after that upload it on my wirecloud instance and then enter my Orion(NGSI server URL,NGSI tenant/service & NGSI scope)and my NGSI Type browser,NGSI browser are working fine but my NGSI Subscription browser widget not working giving the below error:

> Exception details TypeError:
>   this.ngsi_connection.getAvailableSubscriptions is not a function.

I also attached a screenshot of my mashup you can see in this

link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMLNo.jpg.

But when i upload the same mashup(orion admin) on Wirecloud Global instance with same local orion then it working perfectly fine and NGSI Subscription browser also working fine as you can see in the screenshot in this link:https://imgur.com/a/IqPa2Y5. But same mashup with same configuration not working on my fiware lab Node.Can anybody help me how to resolve it?
Wiring Screenshot :https://imgur.com/a/Qs3xxq7 
Error Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/mNoDXAV
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the FIWARE's Lab Store portal (i.e. https://store.lab.fiware.org) is outdated. You can find an updated version of the Orion Admin Mashup (now renamed to Context Broker Admin Mashup) in this repository:

https://github.com/wirecloud-fiware/context-broker-admin-mashup/releases

Comment: Thank you Alvaro Arranz for you reply but when i upload the updated Orion version i.e. v1.0.2 (2018-06-06) in my workspace, it did not getting upload and shows this error : Error parsing config.xml descriptor file: Element .I also attached a screenshot of my error in this link:https://imgur.com/a/f0prc8v.

Comment: This version of the mashup requires WireCloud 1.1, please make sure you are using that version of WireCloud.